# how to return two results from promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using fetch to get data from two different api:s. I need to use both of the api data in the same function. One is finished much faster than the other, so to make this work I have used promise.all. But now I am stuck with two questions.

1. How can I return 2 results (test1 and test2) to the next promise? Right now my code stops and says that "test1 is not defined".
2. If I use promise.all and then run .json on each file (like the code below), will the code wait for each json to finish before returning the result? Or may one not finish?

code:

```
Promise.all([fetch1, fetch2])
    .then((file) => {
      let test1 = file[0].json()
      let test2 = file[1].json()
      return ([test1, test2])
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log(test1)
      console.log(test2)
    })
```

Comment: `push()` each result into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a `Promise.all` on both `.json` calls inside the `.then`:

```
Promise.all([fetch1, fetch2])
    .then((file) => {
      let test1 = file[0].json()
      let test2 = file[1].json()
      return Promise.all([test1, test2])
    }).then(([test1, test2]) => {
      console.log(test1)
      console.log(test2)
    })
```

But it would probably be better to take both `fetch` requests and `.map` them to their `.json()` Promises, *then* call `Promise.all` on the result:

```
const getApi = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
Promise.all([
  getApi('url1'),
  getApi('url2')
])
  .then(([test1, test2]) => {
    // do stuff with test1 and test2
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

The above code will result in the requests being processed in parallel; neither request will prevent the other request from continuing. In contrast, your (tweaked) original code will require the response headers from *both* requests to be received and processed before the `.json()` (to process the body) for either can start.